# OSL Texture usage

Tags: osl

My script is not returning values according to the inputs from my node script. Any assistance would be great. I'm new to osl scripts and can't seem to find any relevant pages regarding texture usage in osl.

```
int GetIndex(int r, int g, int b) {
    if(r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if(r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if(r == 0 && g == 1 && b == 0) {
        return 2;
    } else if(r == 0 && g == 1 && b == 1) {
        return 3;
    } else if(r == 1 && g == 0 && b == 0) {
        return 4;
    } else if(r == 1 && g == 0 && b == 1) {
        return 5;
    } else if(r == 1 && g == 1 && b == 0) {
        return 6;
    } else if(r == 1 && g == 1 && b == 1) { 
        return 7;
    }    
}
shader TextureMask(
    color Mask = color(0.0,0.0,0.0),
    closure color Texture1 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture2 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture3 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture4 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture5 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture6 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture7 = diffuse(N),
    closure color Texture8 = diffuse(N),
    output closure color Shader = diffuse(N)) {
        float r = Mask [1];
        float g = Mask [1];
        float b = Mask [1];
        int _r = 0;
        int _g = 0;
        int _b = 0;
        if(r < 0.5) {
            _r = 0;
        } else {
            _r = 1;
        }
        if(g < 0.5) {
            _g = 0;
        } else {
            _g = 1;
        }
        if(b < 0.5) {
            _b = 0;
        } else {
            _b = 1;
        }
        int index = GetIndex(_r,_g,_b);
        if(index == 0) {
            Shader = Texture1;
        } else if(index == 1) {
            Shader = Texture2;
        } else if(index == 2) {
            Shader = Texture3;
        } else if(index == 3) {
            Shader = Texture4;
        } else if(index == 4) {
            Shader = Texture5;
        } else if(index == 5) {
            Shader = Texture6;
        } else if(index == 6) {
            Shader = Texture7;
        } else if(index == 7) {
            Shader = Texture8;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake getting the `r,g,b` values from the the mask input.

```
float r = Mask [1];
float g = Mask [1];
float b = Mask [1];
```

is only getting the green channel from the mask - it should be

```
float r = Mask [0];
float g = Mask [1];
float b = Mask [2];
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I managed to miss that.